# does standard lib free returned char* variables in C?

Tags: c++, c, malloc

I have a function that returns a `char*`. This char* must not be erased or reused by any other program. I know that in C++ you won't use malloc but you (and I) use `new` to alloc space in memory.

If I do:

```
char buffer[100]; //I just sub'ed rbp at least 100bytes+allign
```

when returned, this space will be no longer attributed to the current function so returning this buffer `ptr` is dangerous.

In conclusion, I was wondering why `stdio` and some other libs can return a char pointer and we don't even bother to free them? they are allocated with malloc or just in stack?
How should I implement my C (only) function to return a char array to be *safe*?

Comment: Depends what they point to. Which function are you thinking of? Did you read the documentation for that function?

Comment: is a function that receives data from a socket fd and returns that. I know that If I malloc that buffer when I return I need to free afterwards. but you know it's boring to do all the same thing. So like inet_net_ntop() returns char* (or const char*) and when I use it I don't care about free or whatever. I just use it and when I'm done it's done. does inet_net_ntop() uses malloc internally ?

Comment: The documentation for a function that returns a pointer should tell (directly or indirectly) you how that pointer needs to be managed. There's no single answer for all functions.

Comment: *I* don't use `new` to alloc space for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Why don't you look at the documentation and find out?](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_net_pton.3.html) (You could run `man inet_net_ntop` on your computer; this is an online version that might be slightly different from your system)

> ## RETURN VALUE
>
> On success, **inet_net_ntop()** returns *pres*.  On error, it returns NULL,
>          and *errno* is set to indicate the cause of the error.

And `pres` is one of the parameters. So it returns the same pointer you gave it, unless there's an error.

Comment: I meant inet_net_ntop. So If I have a function that I need to return a char* so I must use malloc and then free it when not in use? That's the only way?

Comment: @int3 No, it isn't. You can return a pointer to anything you want as long as it's not a local variable.

Comment: so how can I return a non-local variable without using malloc?

Comment: @int3 You seem to be asking how to use a `return` statement. The syntax is `return stuff;` where `stuff` is an expression that evaluates to the value you want to return.

Comment: No I'm not. When you call malloc, you can return that returned ptr and use it  whenever you want. When you are finished you should free it to prevent memory leaks right? So if inet_net_ntop or "char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );" this returned "char*" must be a local. If it isn't a local so it must be a malloc address which I think I must free it right? That's the point! I'm sorry to not being 100% clear.

Comment: @int3 Suppose you have to function `char *func(char *p) {return p;}` - is this allowed? Should you free the return value?

Comment: No I don't because I just passed to the func function from the caller function. if you have: char *func(){char chunk[100]; //do something with this return chunk;} I think it isn't allowed because chunk it is local.

Comment: @int3 That is correct. But my point is that `char *func(char *p) {return p;}` returns a `char*` which *might* not need freeing. (*Might* because what if the caller does `char *p = func(malloc(20));`? Then it would need to `free(p);` at some point)

Comment: You are right. So I have two options. I pass to the function, a local pointer to char chunk[100], to do whatever I want and then I don't even care about returning values because any affect in chunk array will be the same as in the previous function. The other option is inside the called function I return a malloc ptr which I need eventually free later right? No other options? No garbage collection right? :)

Comment: @int3 Your third option is to return a pointer to a static or global variable. And now that you mention it, yes, your fourth option is to use a garbage collector.